# std::list is a cyclic list!! wait, what?

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, containers, stdlist

I was writing a test program and found a very interesting case of `std::list`'s behavior.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    std::list<int>::iterator iter;
    for(int i=3; i<10; ++i){
        mylist.push_back(i);
    }
    iter = mylist.begin();
    iter--;
    iter--;
    std::cout<<*iter<< std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::distance(mylist.end(), mylist.begin())<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
9  
1
```

If I am not mistaken, this behavior is related to cyclic lists. I have never met a forum, book or discussion, in which is mentioned that standard list is a cyclic list. My GCC version is 4.1.2.
So am I correct? Is standard `std::list` a cyclic list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, `std::list` is not cyclic. Your code has undefined behavior when you decrement that iterator. It also has undefined behavior when you call `std::distance(mylist.end(), mylist.begin())`, because `mylist.begin()` is not reachable by incrementing `mylist.end()`.

Note that when you invoke undefined behavior, `std::list` may very well appear to be cyclic, since "std::list appearing to be cyclic" fits in the range of allowable behaviors when the behavior is undefined. That range being, any behavior whatsoever.

Comment: and why the distance between end and begin is 1?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: Your call to `std::distance` is undefined behavior as well.

Comment: how it is determined? because when i count the distance for vector as in this case, the function returns a negative number.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan, The behavior is undefined - it could do _anything_ at all - from setting the iterator to an invalid value at distance 1 from the end, to collapsing the observable universe (up to this moment, I think there are no compiler implementations that collapse the observable universe - but theoretically they could).

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: You can look at your standard library implementation to figure out exactly what is happening, if you want. But the specification of `std::distance` demands that the second argument is reachable by incrementing the first 0 or more times. It also says, regarding standard containers, that decrementing an iterator to come before the `begin()` iterator, or incrementing an iterator to be after the `end()` iterator, is undefined behavior.

Comment: *(note to self: I always get upvotes fastest for the easy questions)*

Comment: The law of inverse proportionality between question difficulty and upvote count. The harder the question, the smaller the population that understand the answer enough to vote. Similar law related obscurity of question to upvote count.

Answer (score 2):

even if it is cyclic **in this implementation** you do not have to rely on it since this property is not guaranteed by the standard.
Also your decrementation of begin pointer is undefined behavior as well as `std::distance` call.

indeed may the list be implemented the following way that may have your observable results:

```
list
  head --> listelem1 (or elEnd)
  begin() return head;
  end()   return head->prev;

listelem1           listelem2           listelem3           elEnd              
     ptr  = d1           ptr  = d2           ptr  = d3           ptr  = nullptr
     next = le2          next = le3          next = elEnd        next = le1
     prev = elEnd        prev = le1          prev = le2          prev = le3
```

But this is up to the implementor of the library as long he follows the interface and behavior requirements of the standard.